How to associate differently tagged aws subnets of the same azs in the same subnet asscociation in terraform
I have 2 subnets tagged as app_private_subnets and 2 subnets tagged as data_app_subnets as seen in the link.

I would like to associate the ones in the same az in the same route table using terraform.

However I haven't found a way to do so as I'm fairly new to Terraform.
My code up to aws_subnet_table_association is below.
main.tf
resource "aws_subnet" "app_private_subnet" {
    count = length(var.app_private_subnet_cidrs)
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.dev_main.id
    cidr_block = element(var.app_private_subnet_cidrs, count.index)
    availability_zone = element(var.azs, count.index)

    tags = {
        name = "Private App Subnet AZ${count.index + 1 }"
    }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "data_private_subnet" {
    count = length(var.data_private_subnet_cidrs)
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.dev_main.id
    cidr_block = element(var.data_private_subnet_cidrs, count.index)
    availability_zone = element(var.azs, count.index)

    tags = {
        name = "Private Data Subnet AZ${count.index + 1 }"
    }
}


resource "aws_route_table" "private_route_table_az1" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.dev_main.id

    route {
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
        gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
    }

    tags = {
        name = "Private Route Table AZ1"
    }
}


resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_route_table_asso_az1" {
    count = length(var.azs[0])
    subnet_id = element(aws_subnet.app_private_subnet[*].id, count.index) # I'm not sure how to add the data_private_subnet
    route_table_id = aws_route_table.private_route_table_az1.id
}

variables.tf
variable "app_private_subnet_cidrs" {
    type = list(string)
    description = "App Subnet CIDR List"
    default = ["10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
}

variable "data_private_subnet_cidrs" {
    type = list(string)
    description = "Data Subnet CIDR List"
    default = ["10.0.4.0/24", "10.0.5.0/24"]
}

variable "azs" {
    type = list(string)
    description = "Availability zones"
    default = ["eu-west-1a", "eu-west-1b"]
}

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

what do you think this length(var.azs[0]) would be?

Here is one way you can do it using for_each, You should read more about here:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each
variable "subnet_cidrs" {
  type = map()

  default = {
    "10.0.2.0/24" : {
      name = "Private App"
      az   = "eu-west-1a"
    },

    "10.0.3.0/24" : {
      name = "Private App"
      az   = "eu-west-1b"
    },

    "10.0.4.0/24" : {
      name = "Private Data"
      az   = "eu-west-1a"
    },

    "10.0.5.0/24" : {
      name = "Private Data"
      az   = "eu-west-1b"
    }
  }
}

As you can see I'm changing the input variables, this is to get away with just one, this structure is easier to loop, and in my opinion also easier to read this way.
Here is the terraform code:
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  for_each          = var.subnet_cidrs
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.dev_main.id
  cidr_block        = each.key
  availability_zone = each.value.az
  tags = {
    name = "${each.value.name} Subnet ${each.value.az}"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_route_table_asso_az1" {
  for_each       = aws_subnet.private
  subnet_id      = each.value.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private_route_table_az1.id
}


Thanks a lot for correcting and answering my question @Helder Sepulveda, it is much appreciated but it doesn't still solve my issue because I want to associate them in 2 separate  aws_route_table_association according to their azs. For example, Private App AZ1 and Private Data AZ1 will be in the same aws_route_table_association  as they are both ineu-west-1a availability zone.
